# Угол поворота в Unity

Tags: unity3d

Интересно понять почему если вращать объект в Unity вокруг оси x ,то вверх идет уменьшение угла x,а если вести камеру вниз,то угол x увеличивается?Из-за это не пойму почему надо вычитать угол,а не ,собственно,прибавлять.

Answer (score 2):

Потому что в Unity выбрана левосторонняя система координат.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если расположить большой палец по оси вращения (X в данном случае), то угол будет возрастать при вращении по направлению остальных пальцев и уменьшаться в обратном случае.